# Apache Utility "ab", what are all of these extra requests?

Tags: node.js, apache, http, wireshark, apachebench

I'm currently testing out node.js on a server and was performing some really basic benchmarking with Apache's "ab" utility and it's giving me results that make me scratch my head.

So, just a real quick background of the setup and the "control".

-I have node.js set up on a server, and when you hit the address it responds with a single line

```
"<html><body>hello</body></html>"
```

-The header of the resopnse is set correctly so that the browser knows the type of data coming back

```
"Content-Type": "text/html"
```

When I request this from a web browser everything works out great. I used Wireshark to view the back and forth between my browser and the server and it looks pretty normal:

```
Source           Destination      Protocol      Info

10.1.10.51     | xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | TCP         | 50281 > http [SYN] 
10.1.10.51     | xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | HTTP        | GET / HTTP/1.1 
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | 10.1.10.51     | TCP         | http > 50281 [SYN ACK]
10.1.10.51     | xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | TCP         | 50281 > http [ACK]
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | 10.1.10.51     | TCP         | [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
10.1.10.51     | xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | TCP         | 50278 > http [ACK]
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | 10.1.10.51     | HTTP        | HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (text/html)
```

The issue arrises when I use Apache's "ab" to test the exact same thing, here is the command I run:

```
sudo ab -n 1 http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/
```

Now, "ab" exits fine and gives a report that I expect, but when I actually view the traffic over on the node.js server and through Wireshark I'm seeing some traffic I can't quite square
As you can see I specify only **1** request. However when I look at the packets over at Wireshark I see a lot more than just a single request.

```
Source           Destination      Protocol       Info

10.1.10.51     | xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | TCP          | 50314 > http [SYN] 
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | 10.1.10.51     | TCP          | http > 50314 [SYN ACK]
10.1.10.51     | xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | TCP          | 50314 > http [ACK]
10.1.10.51     | xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | HTTP         | GET / HTTP/1.0 
10.1.10.51     | xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | HTTP         | GET / HTTP/1.0 GET / HTTP/1.0 GET / HTTP/1.0 GET / HTTP...
10.1.10.51     | xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | HTTP         | GET / HTTP/1.0 
10.1.10.51     | xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | HTTP         | GET / HTTP/1.0 GET / HTTP/1.0 GET / HTTP/1.0 GET / HTTP...
10.1.10.51     | xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | HTTP         | GET / HTTP/1.0 
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | 10.1.10.51     | TCP          | http > 50314 [ACK] 
10.1.10.51     | xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | HTTP         | GET / HTTP/1.0 GET / HTTP/1.0 GET / HTTP/1.0 GET / HTTP...
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | 10.1.10.51     | TCP          | http > 50314 [ACK]
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | 10.1.10.51     | TCP          | http > 50314 [ACK]
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | 10.1.10.51     | TCP          | http > 50314 [ACK]
10.1.10.51     | xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | HTTP         | GET / HTTP/1.0 GET / HTTP/1.0 GET / HTTP/1.0 GET / HTTP...
10.1.10.51     | xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | HTTP         | GET / HTTP/1.0 GET / HTTP/1.0 GET / HTTP/1.0 GET / HTTP...
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | 10.1.10.51     | TCP          | http > 50314 [ACK]
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | 10.1.10.51     | TCP          | [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
10.1.10.51     | xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | HTTP         | GET / HTTP/1.0 
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | 10.1.10.51     | HTTP         | HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (text/html)
10.1.10.51     | xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | TCP          | 50314 > http [ACK]
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | 10.1.10.51     | TCP          | http > 50314 [RST]
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | 10.1.10.51     | TCP          | http > 50314 [RST]
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | 10.1.10.51     | TCP          | http > 50314 [RST]
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | 10.1.10.51     | TCP          | http > 50314 [RST]
xxx.xx.xxx.xx  | 10.1.10.51     | TCP          | http > 50314 [RST]
```

I assume that "ab" makes extra requests as part of it's profiling procedure, but it's also causing node.js to respond to every "GET".
I don't feel like that is so much of a problem if this is "expected" behavior from "ab", but I would like to know for sure, instead of assuming.

When I specify **1** request to "ab" I expect **1** request, but I could be missing something about how this utility works.

Any thoughts or links to the appropriate sections of the manuals would be appreciated

Thanks.